# blackberry java display Select a sound profile popup

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How can I display "Select a Sound Profile" popup programmatically? it's the popup that is displayed when you click the icon Sounds on the top left corner on BlackBerry home screen.

Comment: Have you done any research on this?

Comment: Yes I have, I've googled this and come up with no result. NotificationsManager does not have this function also, it only allow you basically to register / unregister your notification source. Why the downvote? have you had the answer for this?

Comment: "Have you done any research on this?"  Do you have any evidence that this can be done from third party application code?  How do you know it's not something only RIM can implement?

Comment: Yes it can be done. See Whatsapp, click the Settings menu, and choose System Profiles. This is the effect that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for all of you that is still searching for this, I've found the solution. The clue is, you need to invoke "net_rim_bb_profiles_app". Thanks for all the help :p.